# AngularJS (Ionic Framework) - changing State within controller doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

What I am trying to do is within the Search controller, once I get the search results back from the server ($http) change view to a different view - the search results view. I am not sure if the approach I am going about it is right, but either-way it doesn't seem to be working. I will need to pass the response as well, so the new view can display the results/response.

My app.js:

```
.....state('tab.search', {
  url: '/search',
  views: {
      'tab-search': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl as search'
      }
  }
})
.state('tab.search-results', {
  url: '/results',
  views: {
      'tab-search-results': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search-results.html',
          controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults'
      }
  }
})
```

Then my search controller has:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location, $ionicPopup, service) {
....
 $scope.doSearch = function(state) {
    .....
    var result  = service.doSearch(dataObj);
    result.then(function(response) {
        console.log("I'm here");
        $state.go('tab.search-results');
        ......
```

My search results view (tab-search-results.html) has the following basic code at the moment:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search Results">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        hello world
     </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This basic structure is how all my other pages/views are setup too.

What happens when I perform the search is that the console message gets outputted, and then the URL changes to /results as per the **tab.search-results** state, but the template/view doesn't change/show.

Interestingly if I change $state.go('tab.search-results'); to point to another app state/view that I know works, it works perfectly - but for whatever reason this state/view isn't working.

Also, if there is a better way of achieving this same thing, then please let me know.  I will be needing to eventually pass the "response" from SearchCtrl to SearchResultsCtrl - or rather access it on the search results page in one form or another.

Many thanks.

Comment: will you please create a sample  in plunkr or fiddle i will resolve it because this is html loading issue like you put wrong url or state name

Comment: would you please create a sample in plunkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `$stateParams`.

```
var result  = service.doSearch(dataObj);
result.then(function(response) {
  $state.go('tab.search-results', {'searchData':response});
}
```

In your `routes` file:

```
.state('tab.search-results', {
  url: '/results/:searchData',
  views: {
      'tab-search-results': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search-results.html',
          controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults'
      }
  }
})
```

And in your `SearchResultsCtrl`:

```
.controller($stateParams) {
  console.log($stateParams.searchData) // will give you search results
}
```

**NOTE:**If you don't want to pass data through the URL you can use `params` key in the `.state()` method.

```
.state('tab.search-results', {
  url: '/results',
  params: {
    'searchData':null
  },
  views: {
      'tab-search-results': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search-results.html',
          controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults'
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I worked out the problem. It was putting the search results under the tab abstract state. eg: tab.search-results rather than search-results - I am guessing this was the problem as there is no search results tab. When I re-named the state to just search-results (and modified the $state.go to use 'search-results' instead of 'tab.search-results') it worked. Does this seem right?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this as the answer as it answered part of my question on how to pass data. I realised why my view change wasn't working properly too.

Answer (score 1):

I realised why my view wasn't changing properly. The fix was changing the views in the sub-view to reference the parent view.

**Fail (sub-view has unique name from parent):**

```
.....state('tab.search', {
  url: '/search',
  views: {
      'tab-search': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl as search'
      }
  }
})
.state('tab.search-results', {
  url: '/results',
  views: {
      'tab-search-results': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search-results.html',
          controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults'
      }
  }
})
```

**Success (sub-view references parent, 'tab-search'):**

```
.....state('tab.search', {
  url: '/search',
  views: {
      'tab-search': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl as search'
      }
  }
})
.state('tab.search-results', {
  url: '/results',
  views: {
      'tab-search': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search-results.html',
          controller: 'SearchResultsCtrl as searchResults'
      }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I think I worked out the problem. It was putting the search results page under the tab abstract state. eg: tab.search-results rather than search-results - I am guessing this was the problem as there is no search results tab. When I re-named the state to just search-results (and modified the $state.go to use 'search-results' instead of 'tab.search-results') it worked. Does this seem right?